# convert decimal(letters) to binary

Tags: c, binary, decimal

I have to convert a letter to binary number. All work but with one problem - I don`t understand why after my binary number it still prints some other numbers... Can someone help, please?

Here is my code. Thank you in advance!

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void convert(const char char, bool bits[8]) {
    char c = char;
    for (int j = 7; j+1 > 0; j--){
        if(c>=(1<<j)){
            c=c-(1<<j);
            printf("1");
        }else{
        printf("0");
        }
    }
//here start to prints other numbers
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
}


int main(){
    bool bits1[8];
    encode_char('A', bits1);
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    printf("%d", bits1[i]);
}
    printf("\n");
return0;
}
```

Comment: Your code does not print anything, because it doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 problems making your sample code unable to compile:

1. You tried to declare the first argument to your function as `const char char`, but `char` is a type and is not valid variable name.
2. You tried to call `encode_char` in main, but you defined `convert`
3. `return0` should be `return 0`

After fixing those, there will still be a problem with garbage values.
Because even though you passed `bits`, the function never does anything with it (so it remains with garbage values).
So your `printf("%d", bits1[i]);` will be just a bunch of "random" numbers. The extra numbers are not from what you marked with `//here...`.

Here is an example that assigns useful values to `bits`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void encode_char(const char input_char, bool bits[8]) {
    char c = input_char;
    for (int j = 7; j >= 0; j--){
        if(c>=(1<<j)){
            c=c-(1<<j);
            bits[7-j] = 1;
        }else{
            bits[7-j] = 0;
        }
    } 
}


int main(){
    bool bits1[8];
    encode_char('A', bits1);
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", bits1[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: yes, I thought about this garbage too, okay, I understand where was my problem, thank you very much!!!!